# Table with three cells: auto-resize left and right in pure CSS

Tags: css

I have three entities in a row, currently I use table to display them:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id='td1'>some text</td>
      <td id='td2' style='width:600px;'>some text</td>
      <td id='td3'>some text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need is to resize left and right cells simultaneously when browser resizes. I wonder if it is possible without JS.

I have even tried [CSS resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) which apparently does not work in IE, played with widths of the cells, but still without any success. I am totally a newbie in CSS.

Is it even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't verify since I'm on a mobile but have you tried....

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col class="first" />
        <col />
        <col class="last" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then use the `col.first` and `col.last` classes to style them with css.

W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/col.html

Oh, and, remove all the css from your html. Having css inline will make the document completely unmaintainable through css files. And remove the IDs also from td:s and always use " to quote html attribute values.

You can also try to add:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

To prevent the browser from calculating the initial width of each cell according to their contents and give them all initially an equal width. (height will still expand according to content.) Then override certain columns with css.

Comment: Thanks, it works with `.first, .last { resize:both; width:300px; }` (probably not with IE, though). As for IDs and inline CSS, it is not a working example, I simply did not want to mess the example up with CSS block.

Comment: Good that it worked.  People here are quite used to read html and css separately. Doing otherwise may even decrease the readability. For more complex problems you can make a working example in jsfiddle.net and include the core html/css in your post with a link to the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
table{
width:100%;
}
```

it works.